# Raycaster with threejs and draw points on the plane by clicking

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hellow everyone ,I had some question with my procedure about threejs with Raycaster
I add a plane to scene and I want to draw a point by clicking on the plane,but the DOM don't fill the screen

Here is my selection handler， used in vue.js:

```
const canvas = this.$refs.dreamview.getBoundingClientRect();
const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();
pointer.x =((event.clientX - canvas.left) /canvas.width) *2 1;
pointer.y =-((event.clientY - canvas.top) /canvas.height) *2 +1;
this.raycaster.setFromCamera(pointer, this.camera);
const intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children, false);
let plane = intersects.find((e) => e.object.name === "plane");
```

I get the set of coordinates using the code above，but the `plane.point` is incorrect，i don't understand  what went wrong;

Thank you all for any advice that you could give on this.

Comment: what's the output of `console.log(intersects)`? I mean, are you definitely sure it intersects?

Comment: thank you for answering,i get the intersects , it is a aray and i can filter the plane from the Array,,but when i get the `points` of the plane item , but using the coordinate points to draw the point ；It's not where the mouse clicked，but In a nearby location